# How to enable autocomplete for writing in English?

Tags: autocompletion

Is there a way to enable autocomplete for writing in English? For example, if I write `giv`, I want Vim to automatically suggest `give`, `given`, `gives`, `giving`, `giveaway`, etc.

In Emacs, this is easy to enable when using the company-mode package ([source](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18304/optimal-settings-for-auto-complete-for-writing-papers-prose-in-natural-languag)). How can I do this in Vim?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> sequence to initiate completion from keywords in a dictionary. See [`:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K`](https://vimhelp.org/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-X_CTRL-K) for an entry point to configuring and using this feature.

Perhaps the best way to enable this feature is to [enable spell checking](https://vimhelp.org/spell.txt.html), since Vim is able to use the spell checking dictionaries (typically shipped with the Vim runtimes) to complete keywords with the default setting. Typically all you need to do is issue a `:set spell` command to enable spell checking and that will unlock keyword completion with it.

An alternative is to set the [`'dictionary'`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27dictionary%27) option to point to one or more files (such as `/usr/share/dict/words` on Linux and other Unix-like systems) containing lists of words to use for keyword completion.

You can also combine both options of spell checking dictionaries and word list files by including a special literal `spell` as part of the list of paths in the `'dictionary'` setting. For example:

```
set dictionary=spell,/usr/share/dict/words
```

One more advantage of leveraging the spell checking system for dictionary keyword completion is that you have a handy way of adding new acceptable completion targets, by simply marking them as good words for the spell checking system, which you can easily do with the [`zg`](https://vimhelp.org/spell.txt.html#zg) command.

Comment: Is there any way to enable as-you-type autocomplete without having to press `CTRL-X CTRL-K` every single time?

Comment: @Flux You will need a plug-in for as-you-type completion. YouCompleteMe is one such plug-in that does as-you-type completion, but unfortunately [it doesn't support completion from a dictionary](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/issues/138). You might want to look into SuperTab. While it doesn't trigger completion menu automatically, it definitely improves the completion interface...

Comment: MUcomplete does the job https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-mucomplete

Comment: For word lists sorted by word frequency for use by Vim's dictionary completion: https://github.com/Konfekt/complete-common-words.vim

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/cwfoo/vim-text-omnicomplete. It is an omnicomplete plugin for English words, and it is automatically enabled in text files (`*.txt`, `README`). Advantages over Vim's dictionary completion:

- It orders its suggestions by word frequency. More common words would be suggested before less common ones.
- It is able to suggest matches based on the previous word. For example, if you have typed "annual", the plugin would suggest "meeting", "payroll", "report", etc. as possible candidates.

Disadvantage: if you are already using another omnicomplete plugin for the file you are editing, you probably cannot use this plugin at the same time.